# SVPullToRefreshPositionBottom Property not set in swift 3.0

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

I use SVPullToRefresh for refreshing collectionView.Its working when it pull from top but it position property that is position:SVPullToRefreshPositionBottom is not set.Please help me

Here is the code

```
self.collectionView.addPullToRefresh(actionHandler: {() -> Void in
            self.pagination()

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one it working fine

```
collection .addPullToRefresh(actionHandler: {}, position: .bottom)
```

Comment: thank for answering me but its not work it give an error "Extra parameter position in call"

Comment: you may be use old SVPullToRefresh so download new form  https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh

Comment: yes follow this tutorail but still not working i use pod 'SVPullToRefresh'